# root_path goes to an rss feed instead of root page Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss

routes.rb:

```
...    
root 'pages#home'
...
```

Pages controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def directions
  end
...
```

The feed div on the home page:

```
<div>
<p><strong>Sunday's Scripture Readings:</strong></p>
<script src="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Flectionary.library.vanderbilt.edu%2Ffeeds%2Flectionary.xml&desc=1" type="text/javascript" > </script></p>
</div>
```

Whether I use the "back" or "root_path" the url is correct but the content isn't the home page, but rather the rss feed:

```
February 28, 2016: Third Sunday in Lent (Year C)
Isaiah 55:1-9 * Psalm 63:1-8 * 1 Corinthians 10:1-13 * Luke 13:1-9
```

I tried adding a # tag, to go to a specific div on the home page, but that didn't work. Now when I'm on the page that shows the feed, I can hit the refresh and it will go to the home page. But I can't expect my users to know that. Any suggestions? I noticed a similar situation involving Wordpress and rss, but there were no answers. Is it a javascript thing?

Answer (score 0):

`_path` helpers generate relative URLs, so all your URLs are relative to the RSS feed.

To generate absolute URLs, use `_url` helpers.

So, for example, instead of using `root_path` use `root_url`.

For more information, check [the official docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers).